# What is different between arguments and parameter of functions in PHP?

Tags: php

I don't understand difference of arguments and parameter in function.Is there anybody who tell me details about arguments and parameters. What is arguments and what is parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To be simple -

> Variables used in function definition are parameter.
>   Values passed during function call are arguments

```
function abc($x)
{
//----
//$x is parameter..
}

abc(35); //35 is an argument
```